# Running custom command at Visual Studio Installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How to program and run a custom service installation command through the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer? I want to execute the command during the msi installation process.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click your Installer project, go to View->Custom Actions.

Now, if you'd like to execute something *during the installation* process, you should add a custom action to the **Install** section.
If you want to execute something *after the installation* is finished, add a custom action to the **Commit** section.

You can execute EXEs, DLLs (make sure your Class Library inherits from the `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` class), and also scripts (JS and VBS).
Creating Custom Action DLLs is pretty straight forward. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx) MSDN walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a command during the MSI installation process, you would put the custom action in the Custom Actions section by adding into the Commit section.